# What is the Paperwhite 3 Collections Cover Size?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, collections

What is the size of the collections "cover" on the Kindle Paperwhite 3?  I'd like to resize the book covers so that everything is the same size.

It's OCD I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently downloaded a book from Amazon and noticed that the book cover was really close in size to the collections size.  I downloaded the book manually from my content and imported into calibre and it said that the size of the cover was **926wx1400h**.  After resizing my side loaded books my problem is solved.